# CSS "properties of .x" syntax

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to add additional rules to a css block when using a "{ (properties of x) }" selector?

I looked at references but I can't find anything related to "properties of x". A link would be wonderful. I tried the following two combinations, but neither worked:

```
.dock li { (properties of grid_2; display:inline; background-color:#666; ) }
.dock li { display:inline; background-color:#666; (properties of grid_2) }
```

Many thanks!

**EDIT**

Apparently I misread an article and thought that such a syntax existed. I thought one could create a class and let it inherit the properties of another using such syntax, which is evidently not the case.

Comment: Uh... you mean having the CSS properties of another element (x) applied to the one you're working with?

Comment: Sorry, I thought there was some type of feature in CSS where you could  create a class and assign it the properties of another using a (properties of *)... I misread an article and ended up with that crazy idea! My bad!

Comment: I think I found the article the OP was referring to. See the "Grant Grid Properties to Certain Elements" section on [this site](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/03/fight-div-itis-and-class-itis-with-the-960-grid-system/).

Comment: @Anthony, that's the one! Haha! I don't understand why I misread the pseudo-code like that. I guess because it was in code blocks :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS does not have such a feature.

Comment: Mind telling us what feature is the OP asking for?

Comment: @Yi: I assumed the same as you did (explicit inheritance)

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is not possible. I think there are two other possibilities you could maybe use. The first is, that you need to know that several styles can be applied to an element at the same time. I'll give you an example:

```
li { font-size: 10pt; }
.dock li { color: #ff0000; }
```

All list items will be formatted with a font size of 10 points and only those within an element containing the dock class will be red.

My second suggestion is that you try applying two or more classes to your HTML element, for instance:

```
.grid li { font-size: 10pt; }
.dock li { color: #ff0000; }
```

Now put the grid and dock class into your HTML, and the elements will apply both style definitions:

```
<ul class="grid dock"> ...
```

Whatever you consider best for your project: remember that the properties defined in the second style overwrite the properties of the first one (if they do not define the same properties at all, there will be no confusion).

Answer (score 1):

maybe your question is not too strange..

What I understand is that you want to do something like:

```
.a { prop1: val; prop2: val; }
.b { prop3: val; prop4: val; }
.c { .a; .b; prop5: val; prop6: val; }
```

You want the class .c to inherit all the properties and values of .a and .b

If this is ok, you can do that using LESS.

To use your LESS code in your sites you have different ways to do it.

First of all check the original site: [LESS.org](http://lesscss.org/)
If you are on Mac check this site: [LESS APP + PLUGINS](http://incident57.com/coda/)
If you are on PC the less.js plugin should be easier to implement LESS in your sites: [less.js usage](http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/)

Hope it helps.

Happy coding y'all! :)